# Error : 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
donor_df=pd.read_csv('Election_Donor_Data.csv')
top_donor=donor_df['contb_receipt_amt'].copy()
top_donor.sort()
top_donor
```

sort method is not getting applied on top_donor giving an error.why?

Comment: The method is `sort_values` now. You also need to assign it back: `top_donor = top_donor.sort_values()`.